# Json Deserialize string error

Tags: c#, json

```
private void ExmpDatasave()
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("dataSet");
         dataSet.Namespace = "NetFrameWork";
         DataTable table = new DataTable();
         DataColumn idColumn = new DataColumn("id", typeof(int));
         idColumn.AutoIncrement = true;

         DataColumn itemColumn = new DataColumn("item");
         table.Columns.Add(idColumn);
         table.Columns.Add(itemColumn);
        dataSet.Tables.Add(table);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
            newRow["item"] = "item " + i;
            table.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }

        dataSet.AcceptChanges();

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.None);
         Helper.WriteToJson(json);
    }

    private void ExmpDataread()
    {

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("exmp.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();

            var myJSONString = json.ToString();

            DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);
            DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables["Table1"];
            Console.WriteLine(dataTable.Rows.Count);
        }
    }
```

Hey its my brief code `ExmpDatasave()` is used to save a entire data in json works fine; `ExmpDataread` gives error:

> Unexpected end when reading DataSet. Path '', line 1, position 78.

My json values `"{\"Table1\":[{\"id\":0,\"item\":\"item 0\"},{\"id\":1,\"item\":\"item 1\"}]}"`
Please help me to figure out. Thank you in advance..

Comment: Are the \" also part of the json data? If yes, then it's invalid JSON

Comment: I don't no why its coming'\'

Comment: So first make sure you have valid JSON value

Comment: @AndréSchild It's a C string representation of the JSON string, and it's perfectly valid if you're writing it as a constant.  If that's what the content of the file looks like then there's an issue, but the code posted above produces the right data on my PC and reproduces the datatable from the string.

Comment: working perfectly with me.

Comment: that's a debug view of the `json` string

Comment: Working fine here too. Try assigning that value to json variable manually. If it works than you have a problem with reading the contents from disk, otherwise looks good to me

Answer (score 0):

I experience this exact issue and although I wasn't savvy enough to resolve the issue I was able to work around it and for the better I think.

I decided to use Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; to get similar results

```
            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd());
            JObject js = JObject.Parse(json);
            Console.Writeline(js["Table1"].Count);
```

I wouldn't consider this a full answer as I was never able to figure out why It is giving the error when everything says it shouldn't be. But I was rather happy to find this path so I hope it helps